# Anagrams with Generating Functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, generating-functions

Consider the letters {a, b, c, d}. How many 5-letter sequences containing an even number of b's and odd d's exist?

How to approach this problem using generating functions?

Comment: I am not certain that generating functions are the good tool when there is no commutativity (how to take into account for example that "aabcd" is different from "abdca" ?)

Comment: In this case, the property being investigated is invariant under permutation, so it should be fine to use commutative generating functions—which would naturally count each string with the multiplicity of its permutations.

Comment: @JeanMarie You can use exponential generating functions.

Comment: @Mike Earnest You are right !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Hint

A five letter word is given by partitioning $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ into four parts, an $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ part, and filling the corresponding letter in the spaces in the part. This corresponds exactly to the action of multiplying exponential generating functions.

The EGF for the $a$ part is just $\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$, since there is exactly one way to fill $n$ given spots with $a$, for all $n\ge 0$. The same goes for the $c$ part. However, the EGF for the $b$ part is $\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=(e^x+e^{-x})/2$, since there is $1$ way to fill an even number of spots with $b$'s, and zero ways to fill and odd number of spots.

I leave you to find the EGF for the $c$ parts. Once you have all four EGF's, you need to multiply them all together, extract the coefficient of $x^5$, then multiply by $5!$.

---

**Addendum**: You should get that the number of sequences is $4^4$, and in general the number of $n$ letter sequences is $4^{n-1}$, for all $n\ge 1$. This is begging for a simple bijective proof; here is one. To choose a sequence of length $n$ with an even number of $b$'s and an odd number of $a$'s, choose the first $n-1$ symbols arbitrarily, then...

- If there are an even number of $d$'s and an even number of $b$'s, make the last symbol $d$.
- If there are an odd number of $d$'s and an odd number of $b$'s, make the last symbol $b$.
- If there are an odd number of $d$'s and an even number of $b$'s, make the last symbol $a$.
- If there are an even number of $d$'s and an odd number of $b$'s, make the last symbol $c$, and then replace all $d$'s with $b$'s and all $b$'s with $d'$s.

Comment: I have found these lecture notes https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/exponential.pdf very enlightning for motivating the use of exponential generating functions

Comment: Why do we have to multiply the coefficient of $x ^ 5$ by $5!$ ?

Comment: @gmn_1450 The EGF for a sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is $\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n x^n/n!$. If you extract the coefficient of $x^n$, you get $a_n/n!$. In order to make this $a_n$, you have to multiply the coefficient $a_n/n!$ by $n!$.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It helped me a lot! :)